# Getting Error: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { Flatlist, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class List extends Component {

    state={
        person:[{name:'abhjeet'},{name:'shubham'},{name:'kamal'},{name:'devesh'},{name:'ashu'}]
    }


        render(){
            return(
                      
             <View>
                    <Flatlist 
                        data={[this.state.person]}
                        renderItem={({item})=>{
                        console.log(item)
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
                
            );
        }


}
```

If i remove the Flatlist and use Text it is working with Flatlist it is showing error  I am a beginner
with react native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not rendering something right now. Render a `View` inside your `FlatList`

It is `FlatList` and not `Flatlist`

This should work.

```
   return(           
      <View>
        <FlatList style={{marginTop: 40}}
                  data={person}
                  renderItem={({item})=>(
                    <View>
                    <Text>
                    {item.name}
                    </Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                  />
      </View>   
    );
```

also, `this.state.person` is already a list, no need to use [] again.

check https://snack.expo.io/xiumLsKtD

Comment: same problem again ..Saying --Check the render method of 'List'  This error is located at: in List(created by SceneView).....Myfile name is List.js

Comment: ` myRenderItem = (item) => (
        <View>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      )

        render(){

            return(             
             
                <View>
                    <Flatlist 
                        data={this.state.person}
                        renderItem={this.myRenderItem}
                    />
                </View>
                
            );
        }`

Comment: @AbhijeetGupta sorry couldn't test it earlier. there was a typo at FlatList with lower case l. I have updated my answer with a working code snippet link.

Comment: thnx bro i think i was ignoring the spelling

Comment: @AbhijeetGupta please accept the answer for the question to be considered "closed". thnx!

Comment: and how do i do that i am quite new to this platform

Comment: @AbhijeetGupta You simply need to mark answer as correct (the green check image).